# How to block egress trafic to China and APAC on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

On my GCP bill I have those lines:

```
1- Compute Engine     Network Inter Region Egress from EMEA to APAC
2- Compute Engine     Network Internet Egress from EMEA to APAC
3- Compute Engine     Network Internet Egress from EMEA to China
```

Q1. What's the difference between 1 and 2?

Q2. Does GCP provide an easy way to block egress traffic to APAC or China without needing to create firewall rule with all China IPs? As done here http://www.parkansky.com/china.htm

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Compute Engine     Network Inter Region Egress from EMEA to APAC 2-
>   Compute Engine     Network Internet Egress from EMEA to APAC
>
> Q1. What's the difference between 1 and 2?

The first line shows traffic that traveled across Google's internal backbone between regions. The second shows public Internet traffic that traveled between zones. Pricing is different for each type.

> Does GCP provide an easy way to block egress traffic to APAC or China
>   without needing to create firewall rule with all China IPs?

You have a number of options:

- Create firewall rules via the operating system's firewall
- Create firewall rules via Google Cloud Security Groups
- Create rules for Google Cloud Armor (this requires a load balancer)
- Install a smart software-based firewall that implements geolocation-based blocking policies.

Comment: Thanks. About the first question I should review my project configuration because it isn’t multi-regional so I don’t understand the `Inter Region Egress`, above all on Asia, my project is deployed in Europe. About the 2nd one the last solution seems good but my project runs on GKE. I’ll check Google Cloud Armor since I have a load balancer created from a Kubernetes Ingress resource.

Comment: This has nothing to do with multi-regional services. If you have Premium Network Tier enabled traffic will travel on Google's backbone wherever possible. You do not have a problem, so I would not be concerned. Google will route traffic based upon a number of policies and traffic patterns. Additionally, you cannot change those policies with the exception of choosing Premium or Standard Network Tiers. For EMEA to APAC I believe the standard route is through the US but this can change day-to-day.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to use the geoip module for IPTables. That allows you to whitelist countries.

If it's an important service try spinning up an instance in the same region as your users to get the cheaper intra region egress. It also sounds like you have premium networking on, which uses inter region worm holes.

That said, users might still use the wrong server outside their region if your load balancers are properly configured.

I like premium egress for low bandwidth latency sensitive applications, and let the internet deal with heavy video egress.

See this guide on setting up IPTables and GeoIP

https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/block-ip-range-from-countries-with-geoip-and-iptables/

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Debian/Ubuntu instance:

Prequisites:

```
sudo apt install -y locales
sudo locale-gen en_US
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo su
/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e'install Text::CSV_XS'
exit
sudo localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo apt install -y netfilter-persistent iptables-persistent ipset
```

The locale stuff is in case you're getting locale errors. Use en_CA if you're in Canada (instead of the current en_US), or leave en_US if you're in the United States, or change it to [whatever language/locale you need](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php).

If a dialogue box/screen pops up, it asks if you want to save rules. Save current ipv4 rules, `yes`, save current ipv6 rules, `no`.

Disable ipv6 with `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` and paste at the very bottom:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
Save and exit (ctrl + x then enter, and then ctrl +o).
```

Block Australia and China Egress:
If you need to block other websites, the full list of countries is found [here](https://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/).

In the home directory (`cd ~`), nano block-egress.sh and paste the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "### BLOCKING AUSTRALIA EGRESS ###"
echo

ipset -N block-australia hash:net -exist
ipset -F block-australia

if [ -f "au.zone" ]
then
    rm au.zone
fi

curl -o au.zone -sSL "https://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/au.zone"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Download Finished!"
fi

echo

echo -n "Adding Networks to ipset ..."
for net in `cat au.zone`
do
    ipset -A block-australia $net
done

echo "Done"

echo "### BLOCKING CHINA EGRESS ###"
echo

ipset -N block-china hash:net -exist
ipset -F block-china

if [ -f "cn.zone" ]
then
    rm cn.zone
fi

curl -o cn.zone -sSL "https://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Download Finished!"
fi

echo

echo -n "Adding Networks to ipset ..."
for net in `cat cn.zone`
do
    ipset -A block-china $net
done

echo "Done"

echo "### SAVING IPSET RULES ###"
echo

ipset save > /etc/iptables/ipset

echo "Done"
```

Save, exit, and then make script executable:

```
chmod +x block-egress.sh
```

Create blank ipset file (`sudo mkdir /etc/iptables` first if you get the warning that the folder does not exist):

```
sudo nano /etc/iptables/ipset
```

And save and exit.

Run the scripts:

```
sudo ./block-egress.sh
```

Add the iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m set --match-set block-australia src -j DROP && sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m set --match-set block-china src -j DROP
```

Check with `sudo iptables -L` to make sure the rules are there; s`udo iptables -L -v` for more detailed rules. `sudo iptables -S` will list the rules in the format that’s like the rules.v4 file.

Then save all the current rules to the rules.v4 file (must run as root; I had permission errors if I didn't):

```
sudo su
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
exit
```

*Note: `cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4` will list the rules in the rules.v4 file

Then make the rules persistent after reboot:

```
sudo service netfilter-persistent start
sudo service netfilter-persistent save
sudo service netfilter-persistent reload
```

[Make ipset persistent](https://selivan.github.io/2018/07/27/ipset-save-with-ufw-and-iptables-persistent-and.html):

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/ipset-persistent.service
```

Paste the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=ipset persistent configuration
Before=network.target

# ipset sets should be loaded before iptables
# Because creating iptables rules with names of non-existent sets is not possible
Before=netfilter-persistent.service
Before=ufw.service

ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/iptables/ipset

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/ipset restore -exist -file /etc/iptables/ipset
# Uncomment to save changed sets on reboot
# ExecStop=/sbin/ipset save -file /etc/iptables/ipset
ExecStop=/sbin/ipset flush
ExecStopPost=/sbin/ipset destroy

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

RequiredBy=netfilter-persistent.service
RequiredBy=ufw.service
```

*Note: Unless you first execute `ipset save > /etc/iptables/ipset` (which is included in the script, `block-egress.sh`) then there will be no `/etc/iptables/ipset` file and the service will be inactive (dead).

Save, and then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ipset-persistent.service
sudo systemctl start ipset-persistent.service
```

Add cron job of ipset script to ipdate CIDR ip addresses once a day at 10 pm (or whatever you want) to sudo crontab -e (changing $USER to your username):

```
0 22 * * * /home/$USER/block-egress.sh
```

Save, and then reboot (`sudo reboot`) and check iptables rules to make sure the new rules are still there.

If you want to check cron that has run (at the time you set it):

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

If iptables needs to be reloaded for some reason:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Comment: In my case, I also had to run: `apt-get install libpath-tiny-perl`